# Best way to compare IP addresses quickly

Tags: android, algorithm, ip-address

I'm parsing two CSV files which contains IP addresses.
The first is a source CSV, and the second is a "Blacklist".

Because of the size of the source file, I'm trying to optimize the speed at which I find IP addresses that match the blacklist.

**EDIT:** The blacklist consists of IP Address "Blocks". This means that each record in the blacklist has two IP addresses: A `Start` Block (ex. 216.254.128.0) and an `End` Block. (Ex. 216.254.223.255)

This means that direct lookups etc, will NOT work.

I'm wondering what's the best way to approach this. The brute strength method would be:

```
String[] parts = sourceIP.split("\\."); // String array, each element is text between dots

int hi = 255;
int lo = 0;

int mid = (hi - lo) / 2 ;

if (Integer.valueOf(parts[0]) > mid) {
    mid = lo;
}
```

I could then repeat this for each `part` to decide whether or not the IP address is in the black list.

This seems pretty aggressive and with 4k+ records, this could take a very, very long time.

It could take 10+ iterations to decide each part and that would then have to be repeated to check the "High" part of the IP blocks in the blacklist. That's 80+ iterations per record.

I'm hoping to get some input here to see the best method for comparing IP addresses.

What are your thoughts?

Would it be possible to use a quick bitwise mask to compare values rapidly by serializing `INetAddress`?

**FILE STRUCTURE CLARIFICATION:**

Source IP File:

Contains a list of records from a database. (Aprox 4k). Each record contains names, addresses, emails, and IP Address.

Blacklist:

Contains 4.2k records. Each record is an IP Address "Block". This consists of two IP Addresses. 1. Start and 2. End.

If the record in the Source list has an IP address that's found in the blacklist, I need to save that record and add it to a new file.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this code.

Comment: I'm not using the code at the moment. It's a simple search method for integers to "find" a value's position in an array. I would use it to see if the value exists (It's found somewhere in the blacklist) or if you end up between two record and the source IP address doesn't match either. If that's the case, then the IP address does NOT exist in the blacklist. As I said, it's a pretty brute strength method and I'm hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: any reason you have to store these IPs in a file? seems like there would be a better way to store this many records

Comment: How large is the blacklist? If it's not too large, just load it into memory, converting the IP addresses to integers, and sort. You can then load each address from the source file, convert it to an integer, and do a binary search on the blacklist. Or, you could create a dictionary from the blacklist entries and do direct lookups.

Comment: @bsoist: It's an export from a database. We're trying to search and identify records based on a number of criteria, but the IP Blacklist is the most important for us at the moment.

Comment: @Jim: I can't use a direct look-up because the blacklist consists of IP Address "Blocks". The blacklist contains 4.2k records. Each record has a "Start" and "Stop" for the IP blocks. (Ex: 216.254.128.0 ; 216.254.223.255) A binary search is what I've put in the answer (Sort of) but that's gonna result in a TON of iterations for each record. That's 4.2k records in the blacklist that has to be compared to 4k records from the source.

Comment: Please post a relevant piece of such a file. Until the structure is clear.

Comment: A binary search on 4.2K records will require *at most* 12 probes. So you're talking on the order of 50,000 lookups, total, to check all of your records. That will require less than a second. It will take longer to read the source records from the file than it will to do the searching.

Comment: read your clarification. I have some Python code somewhere that does something just like this. Let me see if I can dig it up.

Comment: @Jim: I didn't realize that going a brute force binary search would be that quick. I guess I'll take that approach then and see if it takes too long. I was worried that 12 (+1 to check the END value for the IP Blocks) probes * 4.2k records would take longer than that. Thanks for the help. I'll come back if it's not working quickly/smoothly.

Comment: @Jim: I suppose I can speed up the entire binary search if there's a simple way to compare the addresses. I can't do a direct `>=` because they aren't integers. Is there a simple method for parsing an IP address for easy comparison in a binary search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're talking IPV4 addresses of the form xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

You can easily convert an IP address into an integer. Each segment (i.e. xxx) is 8 bits (i.e. one byte). So four of them together makes a 32-bit integer. So, given an IP address like "192.168.100.12", you can split it into its four parts, parse each one to a byte and create an integer. Say, for example, that you created a byte array of the segments:

```
ipBytes[0] = 192;
ipBytes[1] = 168;
ipBytes[2] = 100;
ipBytes[3] = 12;
```

You can turn that into an integer:

```
int ipAddress = ipBytes[0];
ipAddress = (ipAddress << 8) | ipBytes[1];
ipAddress = (ipAddress << 8) | ipBytes[2];
ipAddress = (ipAddress << 8) | ipBytes[3];
```

There are more efficient ways to do that, but you get the idea. Your language's runtime library might already have something that'll parse an IP address and give you the bytes to make it an integer.

You have a set of IP address ranges that you want to check your source addresses against. Load each of the ranges into a structure like this:

```
class IPRange
{
    public int startIp;
    public int stopIp;
}
```

And store those in an array or list. Then sort the list by starting IP address.

For each source IP address, convert it to an integer and do a binary search of the list, searching the starting IP address. The source address itself might not be (probably won't be) found, but when the binary search terminates the `mid` value will hold the index of the range whose starting IP address is less than or equal to the source address. You then just have to check the source address against that item's ending IP address to see if it's in the range.

Binary search is O(log n). If you're searching a list of 4,300 ranges, it's going to take at most 13 probes to find an address in the array. That should be plenty fast enough, even when doing 4,000 different searches. You're only talking on the order of 50,000 total probes of the range array.

A couple of notes:

First, as I said above, I assume you're talking about IPV4 addresses. If you're talking about IPV6 addresses, the same concepts still apply but you'll need a 64 bit integer. I don't know enough about IPv6 to say how you'd convert the address to 64 bit integer. Probably you should depend on you runtime library to get the address bytes.

Second: I assume that ranges don't overlap. That is, you won't have something like:

```
start range    end range
192.168.1.1    192.168.2.255
192.168.2.1    192.168.3.255
```

If you have that, then an IP address could fall within either of those ranges. You could potentially construct overlapping ranges that would allow addresses to fall through the cracks. If you have overlapping ranges, the problem becomes a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Wow, what a comprehensive answer. Consequently, I've come to pretty much the same conclusion and am in the process now of implementing the IPv6 portion of the solution. Great answer though. I'm just sad it came after already grinding through a solution myself. XD. For posterity's sake though, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Put both files in a String. Use split(",") to split the ip's in the first string. Loop through the obtained ips array. For every ip search for it in the second String like `blacklist.indexOf("," + ip + ",")` But first add a "," at start and end of blacklist string.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. A direct look-up isn't possible because the Blacklist is a series of IP "Blocks". I'm adding more info to the question now.

Comment: Ok but your extra info is not enough. At least not for me. I don't understand it. Just post a relevant piece from such a file to make it clear.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be more clear on what each file contains. Check the new edit above. I can't paste any real info from the files for legal/privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force it.
Load everything into ram, no reason not to.
Split the ips into a 2d array.
{0:123,123,123,123}
Blacklist into a 3d array.
Now you can start searching for integers.
When you have a match compare the next section.
If source value higher then compare to the END block same section.
When you have a match push to a new array and write it to a file at the end.
If this takes more time to run then it took me to type this then close the porn you have open because your ram is full and its using your page file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data structure called [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). Which is rather efficient performance and storage  wise. As for an example, there's a question here, [Most Efficient way of implementing a BlackList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910130/most-efficient-way-of-implementing-a-blacklist) that has an answer that recommends this.

As far as I know, also Google Chrome uses this technique, as also explained rather nicely at **Matthials Vallentine's** blog post [A Garden Variety of Bloom Filters](http://matthias.vallentin.net/blog/2011/06/a-garden-variety-of-bloom-filters/).

Yet more explanation succinctly can be had found at [Adobe leaked credentials checker](https://adobe.cynic.al/). Some excerpts

> The original leak is about 9.3GB uncompressed, of which 3.3GB is email
>   addresses [...] This means the data can fit into 512MB (i.e. 232 bits)
>   of memory and allows us to perform lookups in constant time [...] An
>   optimal bloom filter which is allowed to occupy 840MB would have
>   practically no false positives at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the most direction solution would be to use an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) to store the blacklist. Then check if the IP intersects with any of the intervals.

You also might want to consider using a Trie/hashtable to get fast lookups where the interval is the same. IE: 216.254.128.0 to 216.254.223.255 can be merged to 216.254.(128.0, 223.255), where the () is the interval. Thus you'd end up with two hash-table lookups (one for 216 and one for 254) then a search in an interval tree, which is likely to only contain a small number of elements.

You can also merge overlapping intervals into a single interval, which can probably be done as you build the interval tree. Which ends up being more like a binary search tree in that case.